# Vue.js v2.0 delimeters

Tags: vuejs2

I'm migrating from Vue.js **v1** to **v2**. Before i was assigning vue delimiters in vue.config, but in version 2 it doesn't work (in components I mean). So how to globally declare delimiters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a migration guide on the VueJS documentation : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html

You can find information about delimiters (the options has been replaced) : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Vue-config-delimiters-replaced

You need to declare delimiters in your vue component :

```
new Vue({
    delimiters: ['${', '}']
})
```